# Path while uploading a file using express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

While uploading a file in express-js, I notice that `path` variable is unlike the path of the file. Is there more to this path ? Is cache involved somehow ?

[image: req.files while uploading a file]

Comment: what is your error here ? Could you elaborate your question, it's not clear!

Comment: There is no error. I am just trying to make sense of what is mentioned against 'path' @Saroj